# Wordpress - Does importing old posts break analytics tracking?

Tags: wordpress, google-analytics, seo

I have a very limited knowledge of SEO/Analytics.  I'm in the process of redesigning a WP site in which, we are starting fresh but still want to import all the old blogposts for SEO exposure.

- We are not changing domains
- if we can help it, we are not changing/altering permalink strings

My plan was to export/import with the main content and SEO meta data.

Assuming the permalinks don't change, and the SEO meta stays the same, will importing the posts into a fresh DB affect how the posts appear in search results?  From what I know, the analytics are tied to the url itself, so that should be ok.

Comment: Analytics is not actually related to your SEO results. And may I suggest that you ask this at webmasters.stackexchange.com ? Since this does not involve any code this is probably off-topic here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Must always try to keep you URL same if you think that the old content still has some importance than try to keep it on your site or don't import it if you think it has no use. If the pages are optimized than you will not be losing any sort of traffic you're getting in the past.
So my advice is import them and try to update the content if they are not useful.